# can we make HTTPClient in iphone,HOW

Tags: iphone, objective-c

sorry i  am  a new comer,i just want to know how we can make HTTP Client in iPhone,like java
we make HTTPClient like

```
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
if(Settingdb.getLocation() != null && Settingdb.getLocation().length()
    httppost = new HttpPost(Settingdb.getLocation());
```

i need this code in iPhone (objective C )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make HTTP request by using [URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165-BCICJDHA)